# Definite integral of the cube root of $x \ln (x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to solve the 2016 [CSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Services_Examination_(India)) question paper for [Math Optional](http://www.upsc.gov.in/sites/default/files/MATH1.pdf)

$$I = \int_{0}^1 \left (x\log \left (\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} dx$$

In my attempt to find $I$, I tried to substitute 
$$t = \log \left (\frac{1}{x}\right) \\\ dt = \frac{x}{-x^2}$$

Even tried taking 
$$t = x\log \left (\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

and then tried by parts. But I am unable to make headway. Any idea what might work? How can I tackle these types of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Set $u = \ln \frac{1}{x}$.

Assuming my scratchwork is correct, I think you should end up with something like $$\int_0^{\infty} \sqrt[3]{u} e^{-\frac{4}{3} u} du.$$

Then make the substitution $\widetilde{u} : = \frac{4}{3} u$ and the result comes out nicely.

Spoiler: Answer is $$\left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{\frac{4}{3}} \frac{\Gamma(1/3)}{3},$$ where $\Gamma$ denotes the gamma-function.

Comment: I reached that point, but I could not proceed past that.

Comment: Happy to include more, but you should be able to get the answer from here. Please accept answer when you feel it is appropriate.

Comment: Oh thanks, I did not know the integral definition of the gamma function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 0):

**Hint = Let $x=e^{-u}$ while keeping the Gamma function in mind.**

Answer (score 0):

Take $x = e^{-3t/4}$
Then $\log\frac{1}{x} = 3t/4$
And $t$ varies from $0$ to $\infty$
Substitute these values in question
You'll get the answer in gamma function

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations we use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).